# Master Pages not reflecting changes after updating Solution

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-masterpage, farm-solution

I'm taking over a project from an existing SharePoint site. I was given all the source code which I assume is the current code. 3 of the project handle different types of master pages currently in use on the site.

I was tasked with removing some shared elements from the master pages. Once I removed the elements I used the `update-spsolution` cmdlet to update the solutions. The solutions updated successfully according the powershell. However, when I checked the sites the changes did not appear. I then retracting, removing, adding, and deploying each solution. But still the changes did not appear on the site or in the master pages in SharePoint Designer.

Is there something I'm doing wrong that would prevent the master page changes from the solution appearing on the site and master pages?

Comment: any way to confirm if the master page on the site collection has been customized after its original deploy? If someone edited the master page, it would end up detached from the original file provisioned by the solution and thus you wouldn't see any change take effect.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist it does appear they have been modified after looking at SharePoint Designer

Comment: Try disabling the feature (that provisions the branding artifacts such as master page, style sheet) and re-activate it.

Comment: @Aveenav That seems to have done the trick. I'll have to do some more testing to see if I can avoid doing that on the production server. Do you think changing back to the default master, deleting this custom one, and then add the solution back would fix the master page issue?

Comment: It should. Just ensure that the custom master page is completely gone (empty the recycle bins as needed - shouldn't really matter, but we are talking about *SharePoint*). Also, about the de-activate/re-activate feature trick, this depends a lot on how the feature has been built, so don't take this as a general rule.